# Error when trying to build an object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Below is a line from my app controller create action:

```
@property = current_user.properties.build(property_params)
```

However, I get the following error when I try to save the `@property` obj.

> undefined method `properties' for nil:NilClass

Comment: So you don't have a current user wherever you are calling this(Which is why it is returning nil).  Without more code I can't do any better than that though.

Comment: omg thanks very much, I forgot to add a before action to the controller

Comment: I've cleaned up the formatting to make this more readable. Welcome to StackOverflow!